# Pacman, make the ghosts chase Pacman

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, pacman

So, in Java right now, for a project, I have to code four ghosts and make them chase Pacman. This is the code I have right now. When I run it, I get the error that the variable "i" at return actions[i] can not be found. Does anyone know why this may be happening? Here's my code.

```
public int[] clyde(Game game)
{

    Defender clyde = game.getDefender(3);
    Attacker pacman = game.getAttacker();
    int direction = clyde.getDirection();
    direction = clyde.getNextDir(pacman.getLocation(), true);
    int[] actions = new int[game.NUM_DEFENDER];
    List<Defender> enemies = game.getDefenders();
    int x = 0;
    if (clyde.isVulnerable())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < actions.length; i++)
        {
            List<game.models.Node> powerpills = game.getPowerPillList();
            Defender defender = enemies.get(i);
            List<Integer> possibleDirs = defender.getPossibleDirs();

            if (possibleDirs.size() != 0)
            {
                actions[i] = possibleDirs.get(Game.rng.nextInt(possibleDirs.size()));
                for (int j = 0; j < powerpills.size(); j++)
                {
                    powerpills = game.getPowerPillList();
                    actions[i] = clyde.getNextDir(pacman.getLocation(), true);

                }
            }
            else
                clyde.getNextDir(pacman.getLocation(), false);

        }



    }
    return actions[i];
```

Comment: Without the code your question is not meaningful. So please don't delete it (see [ask]).

Answer (score 2):

Variable `i` is out of scope in that line. You define `i` inside your forloop where you explore each action/ghost. After the end of the loop, `i` is no longer defined.

Edit: Since your function returns `int []`, shouldn't you be returning `actions` (an array with the action of each ghost) instead of a single action, anyway?

Comment: So, should it just be "return actions;" ?

Comment: @AnnaBelle Absolutely (If I understand the code correctly)

Comment: @AnnaBelle that's correct, look at your return type , it's an array and by writing action[i] , you should also get an error at compile time.